# App quando fechado e reaberto , abrir em eu ultimo estado

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que possui diversas interações com google maps , uma delas é gerar rota de um endereço até o outro utilizando a polyline , se o aplicativo é fechado e reaberto , essa rota some do mapa , preciso fazer com que se caso o cliente fechar o aplicativo , quando ele abrir apareça a mesma rota definida , como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Como você representa a rota, ou seja, qual estrutura você usa?

Comment: Pego os endereços pelo PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Comment: Você pode *serializar* o objeto ou capturar os valores e salvar com `SharedPreferences`.